# OpenAI chatGPT API KEY

Tags: google-chrome-extension, openai-api

I'm currently developing a Google Chrome Extension aimed at scaling recipes and converting them into vegetarian dishes, leveraging the capabilities of ChatGPT. To keep things separate from my personal account, I've created a new email address for a different account specifically for this extension.

In my research, I found that there are specific API keys for different versions of ChatGPT, but I couldn't locate one for the free version, which is simply 3.5. Is there a way to obtain or access the API key for the 3.5 version to integrate it into my extension? I'm confident there must be a designated API key for this version somewhere.

Any insights or guidance on how to acquire the API key for **ChatGPT 3.5** would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on projects in which i am using openAI so many times, in my knowledge there is common key for all models of openAI. The same key is used for GPT3, embedding models, GPT3.5 and all models of openAI, so try with the same it will work for sure.